# On $X$ = {0,1,2}, (1) give an example of a nontrivial topology such that X is connected, and (2) give an example such that X is not connected.

Tags: general-topology

On $X$ = {0,1,2}, (1) give an example of a nontrivial topology such that X is connected, and (2) give an example such that X is not connected.

We know that, nontrivial topology generated on X is the discrete topology (i.e. set of all singletons), therefore $T_1$ = {{0},{1},{2}}. Now, if I consider two open sets U and V that are in X as per the definition of connected spaces, then I will get all the intersections as an empty set, i.e. {0} $\cap$ {1} = {}, and similarly I will get the same for {1} and {2}, and for {0} and {2}. If I take their unions, then it will either contain one of the elements (i.e. either {0} or {1} or {2}), therefore it means their union will be X. So, that means that X is separated since U $\cap$ V = {}, and U $\cup$ V = X holds. but the question says I need to give an example of a non trivial topology where X is connected. I got clueless here.

Can someone help me on this? Appreciate your support and help.

Comment: there are non-trivial topologies on $X$ besides the discrete topology

Comment: ok gotcha, I thought discrete topology is the only non trivial topology and trivial topology are empty sets and X (the topological space).

Comment: there's the discrete topology, there's the trivial (or indiscrete) topology, and there can be other topologies, as the answers show

Comment: hmm I got it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the topology
$$\tau = \{X, \emptyset, \{0, 1\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1\}\}.$$

Comment: I tried doing this, I am getting the intersection of all the open sets as an empty set since you have an empty set in that topology, and their unions will be open sets which are also in topology which means its separated or not connected. But what about the 1st one? It says non trivial topology, I am not sure if this a discrete topology since I know discrete topology is generated only by singletons.

Comment: I think you're not following what it means to be disconnected. In order to be disconnected, you need to be able to find two disjoint open sets whose union is the entire space (except $X$ and $\emptyset$). In the discrete case, there are a few options, e.g. $\{1\}$ and $\{0, 2\}$. In the above case, no two open sets (except $\emptyset$) are disjoint (all of them contain $1$), so the topology is connected.

Answer (score 0):

A topological space is connected if it cannot be written as the disjoint union of $2$ or more open sets.

An example of a connected topology on $X$ is $\{ \emptyset, \{1\},\{1,2\},X\}$.

An example of an disconnected topology is $\{ \emptyset, \{0\} , \{1,2\} , X \}$.

Comment: thanks for sharing this, but we have X = {0,1,2}, so as per that [3] wont work I think.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun Here, I think, $[3] = X$.

Comment: how? [3] ?? Is this a singleton? even if its a singleton it wont work. I hope you are not saying that you are considering a half open interval or closed interval. Even if you consider, it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

The discrete topology works for the one.  Now for the other part, we just need to make sure that $X$ can't be separated.  So how about $\tau=\{\{ 0\},\emptyset,X\}$?  $\tau$ is nontrivial.

Comment: The last one will work but I have been told to work with X =  {0,1,2} so I am sorry this wont work.

Comment: I am working with $X=\{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: ok cool, please work on this.

Answer (score 0):

If $X=\{0,1,2\}$, there are two topologies on it could be called "trivial": the discrete topology $\{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{0,1\}, \{0,2\}, \{1,3\},X\}$, which happens to be disconnected because $X=\{0\} \cup \{1,2\}$ and both sets are open. And the indiscrete topology $\{\emptyset, X\}$ which is connected, as we cannot write $X$ as a union of two *non-empty* disjoint open subsets.

But there are other topologies too:
E.g. $\{\emptyset, \{0\},\{0,1\},\{0,2\},X\}$ in which all non-empty open sets contain $0$, so that $X$ is connected

or $\{\emptyset, \{0\},\{1,2\},X\}$, a partition topology, which is clearly disconnected. Etc.